# How do I add a Google Maps fragment to an existing tabbed project?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I have successfully got Google maps working in Android Studio in an independent application. I also have  a Sliding Tabs application working. Both are from scratch. But, How do I add a Maps fragment to an existing sliding tabs application? I have tried adding a "New > Google > Google Maps Activity" to the Java section along with the other code, which appears to load the libraries and code, but results in problems with the Build/Run configurations?? "Importing" modules don't appear to help, but I am probably doing something wrong. I am happy to set things up manually if I need to, but I don't know how to get all the libraries loaded to make Maps work in an existing application.
Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

A little bit code would be helpful.

Create a `MyMapFragment` that extends `MapFragment` or `SupportMapFragment`.

Then modify your `MainActivity` to load that fragment when clicking on the map-tab.

Also make sure you added the [PlayServices](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html#installmaps) correctly and you inserted a working [maps API key](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html#maps_key) in your manifest.